# What is the I_R current for this avalanche photodiode?

Tags: circuit-analysis, photodiode

This is the datasheet of the APD I got.

[image: Photodiode Datasheet]

There's 'I_R' at test condition for breakdown voltage.

What is this current I_R?

Comment: A quick Google yielded a good result. When the device avalanches, you want to limit the current otherwise the device might melt down.

Comment: I think it is probably the reverse current at the breakdown voltage. The plot of current vs voltage during breakdown has a very steep slope but is not vertical, so perhaps they are defining the reverse current threshold for the start of break down.

Answer (score 1):

The comments are valid-  It's how they define the breakdown voltage.  The reverse voltage at which 2 uA of current flows.